# Print dictionary with multiple values seperated

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictioanry that has a key with more than one value:

```
{'bob': {"flying pigs"}, 'sam':{"open house", "monster dog"}, 'sally':{"glad smile"}}
```

I would like the dictionary on output to look like:

```
bob, flying pigs
sam, open house
sam, monster dog
sally, glad smile
```

My biggest struggle is to get the sam key to print the values on their own line.

Comment: Note that in a dict, each key can only have one value. Here, each value is a set, which can contain more than one item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use 2 for loops to first iterate on keys and value (dictionary) and the 2nd one to iterate on the set (dictionary values).

```
mydict = {'bob': {"flying pigs"}, 'sam':{"open house", "monster dog"}, 'sally':{"glad smile"}}

for key, value in mydict.items():
    for item in value:
        print(key, item, sep=', ')
```

**Output:**

```
bob, flying pigs
sam, open house
sam, monster dog
sally, glad smile
```